# why maps cannot showing in device in ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

My application cannot show google maps, it only show google icon i dnt know why
this below my Config.xml

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.1.1">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="AIzaSyC4QCnAZ6KKvGMnNxS6gW34og8tGzHg658" />
</plugin>
```

this my Html

```
<div #map id="map" style="height: 100%; width:100% "></div>
```

and this my Home.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.LoadMap();
}
LoadMap(){
alert('PLATFORM READY!')
  let element = document.getElementById('map');
  let map: GoogleMap = this.GoogleMaps.create(element, {});
  let latlng = new LatLng(-6.2333,107);
  map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(()=>{
    let position: CameraPosition<LatLng> = {
      target: latlng,
      zoom:10,
      tilt:30
    }
    map.moveCamera(position)
    let markeroptions: MarkerOptions = {
    position: latlng,
    title: 'Position'
  }
  let marker = map.addMarker(markeroptions).then((marker: Marker) => {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
  })
  })
}
```

sometime its working well also the map cannot show again, i dont know why

Comment: Please make sure your plugin is updated and  try https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

Comment: yes,, i have  installed plugin you mean, it still doesn't work

Comment: The API key in Google Maps Android API should have an Android app restriction set. Did you restrict the API key as specified in the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#detailed-guides